# Saving Kinect Frames as screenshots

Tags: c#, computer-vision, kinect, kinect-sdk

I just started Kinect programming and I am quite happy to have been able to display RGB and IR images at the same time.

Now using the screenshot button I am able to save each frame when I want. (same procedure as in the sample SDKs)

So now if I want to continuously save those frames how can I go about doing that?

I am new to C# and Kinect programming general. So can anyone help me?

Thanks;

Answer (score 1):

just try:

```
private unsafe void saveFrame(Object reference)
{
  MultiSourceFrame mSF = (MultiSourceFrame)reference;

  using (var frame = mSF.DepthFrameReference.AcquireFrame())
  {
      if (frame != null)
      {
          using (Microsoft.Kinect.KinectBuffer depthBuffer = frame.LockImageBuffer())
          {
              if ((frame.FrameDescription.Width * frame.FrameDescription.Height) == (depthBuffer.Size / frame.FrameDescription.BytesPerPixel))
              {
                  ushort* frameData = (ushort*)depthBuffer.UnderlyingBuffer;
                  byte[] rawDataConverted = new byte[(int)(depthBuffer.Size / 2)];


                  for (int i = 0; i < (int)(depthBuffer.Size / 2); ++i)
                  {
                      ushort depth = frameData[i];
                      rawDataConverted[i] = (byte)(depth >= frame.DepthMinReliableDistance && depth <= frame.DepthMaxReliableDistance ? (depth) : 0);
                  }

                  String date = string.Format("{0:hh-mm-ss}", DateTime.Now);
                  String filePath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/test/" +date+".raw";
                  File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, rawDataConverted);
                  rawDataConverted = null;

              }
          }
      }
    }
 }
```

You also take a look here:
[Saving raw detph-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883611/kinect-v2-saving-raw-detph-data)